# bootstrap quebra de linha não ocorre

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nav-bar

Boa noite, estou aprendendo a usar o bootstrap 4. fiz um menu usando `navbar` e `nav-brand`, tudo funciona normal mas quando chega nos tamanhos `sm` e `md` por algum motivo o tamanho do background fica menor que os links do menu. Por esse motivo tentei fazer os links ficarem abaixo da logomarca mas os links não descem para outra linha quando coloco o `col-sm-12`. Quando uso o `col-sm-12` fora do `Navbar` ele funciona normalmente.

se algum tiver alguma dica agradeço.
Obrigado

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Curso de Bootstrap</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="../bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="_css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark col-md-12">
                <div class="navbar-header col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="../img/icone_aftereffects_grande.png" width="50em">After Effects</a>
            </div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="info.html">Info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="special-events.html">Special Events</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="dvd.html">DVD</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="location.htm">Location</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="review.html">Review</a></li>                
                </ul>  
                </nav>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <!-- Fim do seu codigo -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="_js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua Navbar está bem diferente do que diz a documentação... Além disso, seu problema de fato se da pq vc está usanda a classe `navbar-expand-sm` na Navbar, só que como vc tem muitos itens no menu o ideal seria usar `navbar-expand-md` para **só expandir a Navbar após 768px de largura.**

Vc pode consultar a documentação completa aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#how-it-works

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código da imagem acima:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark col-12">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="../img/icone_aftereffects_grande.png" width="50em">After Effects</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="info.html">Info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="special-events.html">Special Events</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="dvd.html">DVD</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="location.htm">Location</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="review.html">Review</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Quebrando a linha

Agora se a sua intenção é de fato quebrar a linha ai a indicação é usar as classes Flex do Bootstrap. Nem de CSS extra vc vai precisar...

A Navbar por padrão já tem display:flex, então basta vc determinar que entre telas MD e SM a Navbar vai alinhar os filhos em coluna com a classe `flex-sm-column` e `flex-lg-row` vc controla isso, e depois de SM o menu collapsa `navbar-expand-sm` . Aqui tem a documentação oficial das classes Flex do Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código da imagem acima:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark col-12 flex-sm-column flex-lg-row align-items-start">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="../img/icone_aftereffects_grande.png" width="50em">After Effects</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="info.html">Info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="special-events.html">Special Events</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="dvd.html">DVD</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="location.htm">Location</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="review.html">Review</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era justamente isso que tinha em mente, que o menu apenas colapse depois notamanho SM, mas ainda não sabia que a classe flex servia pra isso. Realmente o meu navbar estava diferente, não tinha colocado a classe "navbar collapse" nem o button com a classe "navbar-toggler". vou testar aqui, obrigado novamente.

Comment: @sarge88 sem problemas amigo, sempre consulte a documentação, ajuda bastante e já tem classe pronta para quase tudo!